# How to save and retrieve an android widget id

Tags: android

I have setup a widget like this

ToggleWidget.java

```
    public class ToggleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static RemoteViews remoteViews;
    boolean status = false;
    static int appWidgetId;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;



        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.toggle_widget);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), WakeService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bulb_widget, pendingIntent);




            if (WakeService.isAwake) {
                remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bulb_widget, R.drawable.bulb_on);

            }
            else {
                remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bulb_widget, R.drawable.bulb_off);

            }

         // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);

    }




}
```

How can i save the ID of every widget i create and delete those that i've deleted with sharedPreferences?

Also from a service i'd like to update the widget like this

```
private void updateWidget(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ToggleWidget.class);
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    int[] ids = {ToggleWidget.appWidgetId};
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

How can i retrieve the saved IDs from the service to make the update?

Comment: you should either accept an answer, or answer the question yourself and select your own answer if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at android's [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) options. Here is how you could use SharedPreferences...

```
public class MyService extends Service{

            //Class used to store data
            private SharedPreferences preferences;
            private int[] ids;
            private int numIds;

            public void retreiveIds(){
                preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                numIds = preferences.getInt("num",0);
                ids = new int[numIds];
                for(int i=0;i<numIds;i++){
                    ids[i] = preferences.getInt("ID"+i,0);
                }
            }

            public void saveIds(){
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = preferences.edit();
                numIds = ids.length;

                //iterate through array and save each id
                for(int i=0;i<numIds;i++){
                    ed.putInt("ID"+i,ids[i]);
                }

                ed.putInt("num",numIds);
                ed.commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Still it's unclear to me how to get the id from the widget.
I've assigned the value of appWidgetId to ids, and when i call the update i pass the ids value in the intent.putExtra

But it doesn't work

Comment: You should be updating all of the ids in the onUpdate() method. Then you do not need to store them. In onUpdate(), just call getAppWidgetIds() and update all of them for your app

Answer (score 1):

In your Reciever class just override **onCreate()** method and under that method,

```
int[] ids = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
```

Then you will get int array, pls check it, it will work...:)

Comment: doesn't work, it can't find the method getIntent()
I think i can't use it in a service
The updateWidget() method is inside a service

Comment: This code you are writing under Receiver's onCreate() or Service's onCreate?, From your code you are sending broadcast "sendBroadcast(intent);" then how will you receive this intent in service?

Comment: the broadcast triggers the onUpdate() of the toggleWidget.java

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it. Code in kotlin:

```
val thisWidget = ComponentName(context, this.javaClass)
val allWidgetIds: IntArray = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget)
```

Now you can use these `allWidgetIds` to update widgets.